# C# DataRow.Delete() is clearing the DataTable when I delete index 0

Tags: c#, datatable

C# DataRow.Delete() is clearing the DataTable when I delete index 0. When I delete the row at index 1 or greater it works fine. The DataTable reportDetails has 215 rows. The first row, index 0, has all nulls. When i = 1 the row at index 1 is deleted and I end up with 214 rows. When i = 0 all rows are deleted.

Here's my code:

```
int i = 0;

DataRow dr = reportDetails.Rows[i];
dr.Delete();
reportDetails.AcceptChanges();
```

What am I missing?
Edit: The same thing happens when I do .RemoveAt(0)

Comment: I think nothing missed with this code, it should work. Can you please share full code where you add Data to DataTable.

Comment: I comes from a very large class that runs an SSRS report, exports to XML, and reads the XML into a DataSet. I worked around this by copying all rows except row[0] into a new table, but it's not a great solution. I did EnforceConstraints = false but that didn't help. I'm thinking it's a dataset constraint.

Comment: Is there a Relation defined on that DataTable?

Comment: Yes. It looks like just that first row has an FK to another table. I guess that explains it. I'm surprised  EnforceConstraints = false doesn't help,but I guess I don't understand how that works either.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The DataTable had Constraints that caused all rows to delete when a specific row was deleted. In this case the row at index 0.  I added this code and now .Delete() works correctly:

```
// Remove any foreign key constraints
for (int i = reportDataSet.Tables.Count - 1; i >= 0; i--)
{
    var table = reportDataSet.Tables[i];
    for (int constraint = table.Constraints.Count - 1; constraint >= 0; constraint--)
        if (table.Constraints.CanRemove(table.Constraints[constraint]))
            table.Constraints.Remove(table.Constraints[constraint]);
}
```

However, the code to copy the DataTable into a new DT without constraints and then remove the row is fewer lines of code. It's also more clear because nobody will have to wonder about DataSet relations or foreign key constraints.